# WebDriverException : Missing 'type' parameter

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, geckodriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver in python. The environment condition of my setup are -

python 2.7.12
selenium 3.4.2
Firefox 52.0.2
Geckodriver v.0.13.0
on running python script following line of code is giving error

```
self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
```

Error message is WebDriverException : Missing 'type' parameter.
Can anyone help me in this situation ?

Comment: Please upgrade your firefox. This is now fixed in Firefox 53 onwards.

Comment: Try with GeckoDriver v0.16.1.

Comment: Dear @ChandaKorat with upgraded version of Firefox it is giving error in  driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(".....") this line. Also I am working for company and their system environment has firefox v_52.0.2

Comment: which error? and please share your all code in question itself.This problem is only due to versioning. You can refer [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3661) and [this](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/511)

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox use the following setup:

- Firefox version:  54
- Selenium Version: 3.4.3
- Python Version: 2.7.13
- Geckodriver: v0.17.0
- Download Link: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases