# cannot get the data from the table of split of one cell by xpath with webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

cannot get the data from the table of split of one cell, thanks !

Python Code

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("url")
print driver.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/p[1]/span').text
print driver.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/p[1]/i').text
print driver.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/p[2]').text
```

Expected Result

```
5    1-1/2    14.34
```

Error Messages:

```
Unable to locate element: //html/body/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/p[1]/span
```

but actually this data existing in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, but your code is checking for an element before the page has been completely loaded.
The simplest thing you could do is add a `wait` condition.

In the code below, the driver polls the HTML for 20 seconds for an element to load.
It doesn't exactly wait for the whole 20 seconds before checking if the element exists, but it waits for the element to load for 20 seconds after which it will throw a `NoSuchElementException`

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(20) # seconds

driver.get("url")
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/p[1]/span').text)
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/p[1]/i').text)
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/p[2]').text)
```

Comment: dear, thanks ! but it showed "Message: Missing 'type' parameter"

Comment: What line does it show it on? Can you paste the exception log?

Comment: yes, dear, "selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: Missing 'type' parameter"

Comment: Well, it seems that the version of firefox that you're using is old. You might need to upgrade to a newer version. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44254222/webdriverexception-missing-type-parameter

Comment: After 20 second element invisible error will not be thrown, it will surely throws the error of NoSuchElementExist exception.